# Sorting a list: int object not callable

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a long and complicated method, I'll give the important parts:

```
def get_itter(self, sort_by=0): #sort_by is set to 0 for debugging purposes

    ...

    r = self.parser(self.in_file) # parse a csv file

    ...

    if type(sort_by) == int:
        r = [i for i in r]
        sort = sorted(r, key=sort_by)
    ...
```

Now my problem is that when I run this code it gives me an error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. Why is it giving me this error?

P.S. I am relatively new to Python and am trying to add some functionality to code that I did not write.

Comment: What kind of sorting were you *expecting* to happen?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have a csv file full of dates, and I need to sort the csv file by date. so that I can run it trough a custom parser and import the data to the system

Comment: And what is `sort_by` supposed to represent? The column number?

Comment: Indeed it does represent the column number. `:)`

Comment: Then jonrsharpe's answer has got you covered; use `itemgetter()` as the sort key. And use `isinstance(sort_by, int)` instead of testing for a fixed type.

Comment: I recommend you to start your scripts in interactive shell (i.e. in IDLE or with "python -i yourscript.py") and type `import pdb; pdb.pm()` to console prompt. `pdb` - is a debugger module and `pm()` - is a Post-Mortem function.
Also you can use any gui debugger and check `locals()` in suspicious places.
`pdb` have also `set_trace()` function that you can include everywhere in your code and do such things as in `pm()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set:

```
sort_by=0
```

*check* it's an `int`

```
if type(sort_by) == int: # note: isinstance(sort_by, int) is preferred here
```

then use it:

```
sorted(r, key=sort_by)
```

When you pass a `key` to `sorted`, it tries to apply that key to all items in the sequence it's sorting, trying to call it with each item, something like:

```
sortvalues = [key(i) for i in seq]
```

If `key` is an integer, you can't call it:

```
0(1)
```

gives the `TypeError` you are seeing.

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but if you want to sort by the `sort_by`th item in a sequence, you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(r, key=itemgetter(sort_by))
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `sort_by` to 0 and then pass that as the key function to `sorted`. Python will call `key` as a function to define the sorting key, which isn't possible for 0.